# Opening sqlite3 database from python in read-only mode

Tags: python, sqlite

While using sqlite3 from C/C++ I learned that it has a open-in-read-only mode option, which is very handy to avoid accidental data-corruption. Is there such a thing in the Python binding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239606/sqlite3-read-only-on-a-file-system-that-doesnt-support-locking

Comment: @Chris Thanks, I will redact an answer just to save some work to future people with the same question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [force python to forego native sqlite3 and use the (installed) latest sqlite3 version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545479/force-python-to-forego-native-sqlite3-and-use-the-installed-latest-sqlite3-ver)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

As of Python 3.4.0 you can open the database in read only mode with the following:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('file:/path/to/database?mode=ro', uri=True)
```

Also see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect).

Comment: for a relative path, no leading `/` character is needed, e.g.: `file:folder/db.sqlite3?mode=ro`

Answer (score 17):

Workaround for Python 2.x:

```
fd = os.open(filename, os.O_RDONLY)
c = sqlite3.connect('/dev/fd/%d' % fd)
os.close(fd)
```

Not posix, but available on Linux, OS/X and most modern unixes.

Comment: can this be combined with a 'with' statement?

Answer (score 15):

Somewhat related, note that you can enable/disable modifications dynamically with a pragma:

```
pragma query_only = ON;   -- disable changes
pragma query_only = OFF;  -- enable changes
```

Answer (score 5):

As by the link given by @Chris, no. But there is another wrapper for sqlite3, which is less PEP 249-compliant and that wraps sqlite3 more tightly, assimilating new features of the engine: https://github.com/rogerbinns/apsw. That wrapper does support opening the database in read-only mode, plus other niceties.