# SQLite query restrictions

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-injection

I am building a little interface where I would like users to be able to write out their **entire** sql statement and then see the data that is returned. However, I don't want a user to be able to do anything funny ie `delete from user_table;`. Actually, the only thing I would like users to be able to do is to run `select` statements. I know there aren't specific users for SQLite, so I am thinking what I am going to have to do, is have a set of rules that reject certain queries. Maybe a regex string or something (regex scares me a little bit). Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

```
def input_is_safe(input):
    input = input.lower()
    if "select" not in input:
        return False
    #more stuff
    return True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest a different approach to your problem. You can restrict the access to your database as read-only. That way even when the users try to execute delete/update queries they will not be able to damage your data.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205744/opening-sqlite3-database-from-python-in-read-only-mode) is the answer for Python on how to open a read-only connection:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('file:/path/to/database?mode=ro', uri=True)
```

Comment: This is much better than keeping 2 database copies and automatically copying one database to the other every time someone gets through my castle wall. Props for thinking out of the box. Thanks.

Comment: Also [PRAGMA query_only = ON](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_query_only).

Comment: @CL, that's very good to know about. But how does the OP make sure nobody sneaks `PRAGMA query_only = OFF; DROP TABLE users` into the query?

Answer (score 0):

Python's sqlite3 [`execute()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) method will only execute a single SQL statement, so if you ensure that all statements start with the `SELECT` keyword, you are reasonably protected from dumb stuff like `SELECT 1; DROP TABLE USERS`. But you should check sqlite's SQL syntax to ensure there is no way to embed a data definition or data modification statement as a subquery.

My personal opinion is that if "regex scares you a little bit", you might as well just put your computer in a box and mail it off to <stereotypical country of hackers>. Letting untrusted users write SQL code is playing with fire, and you need to know what you're doing or you'll get fried.

Comment: I'm not saying that I can't or won't write regex expressions, it's just that I don't feel confident doing it.

Comment: Gotcha. And I'm not saying you really need regexps in particular-- just that you need to be careful and really know what you're getting into.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the database as read only, to prevent any changes.
2. Many statements, such as PRAGMA or ATTACH, can be dangerous. Use an [authorizer callback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.set_authorizer) ([C docs](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/set_authorizer.html)) to allow only SELECTs.
3. Queries can run for a long time, or generate a large amount of data. Use a [progress handler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.set_progress_handler) to abort queries that run for too long.