# Opening sqlite3 database with no write access

Tags: python, sqlite, permissions

I'm trying to perform queries on an SQLite database from Python. Problem is, I do not have write access to the database file, and also not to the directory containing the database file.

When I connect to the database and perform a SELECT query I get an "Unable to open database file" error. I tried following the advice [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21804603/871910), but it didn't work. I guess SQLite fails when trying to create the lock files.

When I have write access to the directory, but not to the sqlite file, I get another error - a locking error. This is because sqlite creates the shm and wal files *with the same permissions as the db file*, meaning I get shm and wal files I can't write to, resulting in a locking error.

Other than copying all files to a directory I do have full access to, is there another way around this?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) says:

> It is not possible to open read-only WAL databases. The opening process must have write privileges for "-shm" wal-index shared memory file associated with the database, if that file exists, or else write access on the directory containing the database file if the "-shm" file does not exist.

To allow read-only access to that database, some user with write permissions needs to change it to some other [journal mode](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode).

Comment: If I have write access to the folder and no write access to the file, the -shm file is created, but I do not have write permission to it (sqlite simply copies the permissions of the db file). This is a bug, I wonder if it's a bug in the Python wrapper or sqlite itself.

Comment: As of version 3.22 (2018-01-22), read-only WAL databases are supported under certain conditions: https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#read_only_databases

Answer (score 0):

You can open a `sqlite3` connection in read mode with the following syntax:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('file:path/to/database.sqlite?mode=ro', uri=True)
```

Comment: This is the answer I've already quoted. It does not work. The connection may be in read-only mode, but the file and directory need to be writable.

Comment: This is not a correct answer, but what was I looking for.